# Possible to hide Play button on iphone for video when responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto/3.7.0/index-5.html

If you check this website, it has a video in the background that plays automatically. However, when you browse the page on a mobile device, for example iphone, the playbutton appears in the background.

is there a way to hide the playbutton when you browse the site on a mobile? and use an image instead perhaps??

Appreciate for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are such means to hide button while playing video. 
The code associated with the iphone are locked and it cant be modified by user